# Problems with Vignéras' proof of Skolem-Noether th. in "Arithmétiques des Algèbres de Quaternions"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, quaternions, morphism

I have some problems in understanding some details in the proof of Skolem-Noether Theorem from Vignéras' book. The statement is

"Let L, L' be two commutative $k$-algebras inside a quaternion algebra $H/k$. Then each $k$-isomorphism of $L$ onto $L'$ lifts to an inner isomorphism of $H$ and all $k$-automorphisms of $H$ are inner automorphisms."

In the proof Vignéras considers a commutative $k$-algebra $L$ different from $k$ and a non trivial $k$-isomorphism of $L$ in $H$, called $g$. She then defines two actions of $L$ on $H$:
$$m.h=mh\quad and \quad m.h=g(m)h$$
where $m\in L$ and $h\in H$.
Then she asserts the existence of a **linear** $k$-endomorphism
of $H$, called $z$, s.t. $z(mh)=g(m)z(h)$.

**First question: why does this $z$ exist?**

Going on in the proof it appears an element $a\not\in L$ and this fact implies $H=L+aL$.

**Second question: why $a\not\in L$?**

**Third question: why $a\not\in L \Rightarrow H=L+aL$?**

I couldn't write down all Vignéras' proof but, if you don't have the book, there is a Pdf english version if you search "the arithmetic of the quaternion algebra" on Google. You can also find it at the link:

[http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~guoxj/notes/qa.pdf](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/%7Eguoxj/notes/qa.pdf)

I noticed a small mistake in this Pdf version: there is written $a\in L$ in place of $a\not\in L$. There might be other mistakes, so be careful.

P.S. I am not english so I hope my writing is acceptable.

P.P.S. I found other versions of Skolem-Noether but I don't think I can apply them cause $L$ is not supposed to be a simple $k$-algebra but just a commutative $k$-algebra.

Thank you in advance :)